# Load multiple tables into Gridview and Save in DB by ASP.NET C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, database, gridview, ado.net

There is a hierarchy (parent-child) relationship between three Tables **A > B > C** in Database ..
I need to load some fields from each table into `GridView` and change data then save it back into the Database by ASP.NET with C# with ADO.NET
But I need a little sample code,
I searched but couldn't find any thing for this scenario ..

Any help, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can loop through the whole GridView, and get data from each row. Then insert these data (each row) into test table row by row :

```
foreach (GridViewRow gvr in GridView1.Rows)
{
    string data1 = gvr.Cells[0].Text;    
      //get data from BoundField in each row
    string data2 = ((Label)gvr.FindControl("Label1")).Text;    
      //get data from control in TemplateField in each row
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("insert_sql", conn);   
      //generate insert sql using above data
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Below is a good link for the same.
The idea is simple, user `gridview events` or `data-source` to display and update the database.

http://www.aspdotnetcodes.com/SQLDataSource_StoredProcedure_Multiple_Tables_Update.aspx

There are many things in `gridview` which you will have to explore.
http://asp-net-example.blogspot.in/search/label/GridView%20Example

Comment: Thanks but i use oledb so don't have stored procedure on it but articles are really useful,